# Using restatable with a custom environment

Tags: environments, theorems

I want to use the `restatable` package with a custom environment. It almost works except when I restate with `\name*` it does not use the original label.

Before you ask, I'm not using newtheorem because its formatting doesn't agree with me needs and using `amsthm`, to my dismay, is not an option.

Here's a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcounter{main}
\newcommand{\envheader}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{main}\par\smallskip \textbf{{#2}~\thesection.\themain.}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else{({#1})}\fi %% Name of the theorem
  }

\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{\envheader{#1}{Theorem}\itshape\/}{\smallskip}
\newenvironment{lemma}[1][]{\envheader{#1}{Lemma}\itshape\/}{\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{theorem}{mytheorem}\label{thm:mytheorem}
  How you doin'?
\end{restatable}

\mytheorem*

\end{document}
```

Here's what I get:

[image: Minimal example output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

restatable expects that the internal counter has the same name as the environment, so you should use theorem instead of main. Side remark: your definition will not prevent page breaks between the theorem title and the body.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcounter{theorem}
\newcommand{\envheader}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{theorem}\par\smallskip \textbf{{#2}~\thesection.\thetheorem.}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else{({#1})}\fi %% Name of the theorem
  }

\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{\envheader{#1}{Theorem}\itshape\/}{\smallskip}
\newenvironment{lemma}[1][]{\envheader{#1}{Lemma}\itshape\/}{\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{theorem}{mytheorem}\label{thm:mytheorem}
  How you doin'?
\end{restatable}

\mytheorem*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works but I'd like to use the same counter for theorem and lemma. I tried to create a theorem counter and do \setcounter{theorem}{\value{main}}, in the environment definition, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: That's a new question so better ask a new question.

Comment: I'd say it's a related question that's definitely implied by my example.